# Schwarz Lemma, an onto map with $f'(0)>0$ is the identity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f$ be $1-1$ holomorphic on unit disk onto itself. It satisfies
(a) $f(0)=0$, (b) $f'(0)>0$. We need to prove that $f(z)$ is equal to $z$.

I am stuck here, because I can prove using Shcwarz Lemma that $f(z)=\lambda z$ for all $z$ in unit disk, where $\lambda = e^{i \theta}$ for some $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$.

I am not able to understand how to use (b) $f'(0)>0$ to say that $\lambda=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f'(0) = \lambda$. As $f'(0) > 0$, $\lambda$ is both real and positive. The only such unit length complex number is $\lambda = 1$.

Comment: yes I thought about this, but I have been a bit confused as I thought $ '>'$ relations in complex quantities meant quantities involving norm on both sides.

Comment: Saying $f'(0) > 0$ implies $f'(0) \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: No. There is no notion of order on $\mathbb{C}$ which is consistent with its algebraic structure. The only complex numbers we can order are real numbers, so the statement $f'(0) > 0$ implies $f'(0) \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry for over-complicating the problem.

Comment: No worries. I personally don't think it is a good idea to say $f'(0) > 0$ without first specifying that $f'(0)$ is real, but that's just me. I can understand why it would be confusing.